# Squarespace index page of index pages

Tags: squarespace

Squarespace allows you to make an index page with the type 'stack', which allows you to make a page made up of smaller pages stacked on one another.

I'm coming into a project where they've made a portfolio using some of these stacked index pages, and they want me to figure out a way to display them in a grid.

My initial thought was to extend a new list type to accept index types:

```
"acceptTypes" : [ "page", "gallery", "index"],
```

unfortunately this only partially worked.  It showed up in the menu and I could add a new list to it, but couldn't fill the stack list with pages.

Is there any way to do this?  I basically want to make a grid of their 'projects' which were implemented in stacked index pages.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want to keep the stacked index AND add a grid-view of them somewhere else on the site, or whether you want to keep the stacked index AND show a grid view on the same page, or whether you want to be rid of the stacked and, in its place, setup a grid-view?

Comment: I want a grid to link to a stacked page.

My friends made their portfolio with stacks, using the full-width headers to break up the content.

I want to use the grid-index to link out to their portfolio pages.  It works 100% just linking to a normal page, but you lose the full width-headers and the organization of using stacks.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, I would use a `<squarespace:query>` to accomplish this, since you are already in developer mode.

https://developers.squarespace.com/squarespace-query

> A query allows you to display items from any collection on any page of your site. A Squarespace Query can be filtered by several parameters.

Basically, within the page upon which you want the grid, you'd do a query into the index where the stacked sections are. This allows you to access the stacked sections directly from "where they are" without having to create another collection and duplicate them. If the sections get updated, the grid will also update.

For example:

```
<squarespace:query collection="my-index">
  <div class="gridWrapper>
    {.section collection}
      {.repeated section collections}
        <div class="gridItem">
          <!-- grid item HTML/JSON-T code here -->
        </div>
      {.end}
    {.end}
  </div>
</squarespace:query>
```

You could copy/paste the grid layout HTML within the scope of the `squarespace:query` if you have access to the source template files (like from the ['Avenue' template](https://avenue-demo.squarespace.com/) for example). If not, you can copy/paste the rendered-source and rewrite it a bit to utilize JSON-T where you need individual item information to appear. Or, write your own grid.

As an example of the data/scope you are iterating over, you can view this URL which is an index page in the Squarespace Brine demo/template. The index page "sections" are in the `collection.collections` scope. As I said, this data can be iterated over via JSON-T similarly to any other Squarespace collection.

https://brine-demo.squarespace.com/?format=json-pretty